# Kohana i18n не всегда срабатывает

Tags: i18n, kohana

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите пожалуйста почему может не срабатывать

```
':field must not exceed :param characters long' => ':field это поле не может содержать больше :param символов',
```

Но срабатывает вот это

```
':field must not be empty' => ':field это поле не может быть пустым',
```

Даже если в первом варианте убрать :prarm2 то все равно не сработает.
Использую

```
<?foreach ($errors as $error) {?>
   <li><?=__($error)?></li>
 <?}?>
```

Заранее благодарю за подсказки и ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
':field must be exactly :param2 characters long'       => ':field должно быть длиной :param2 символов',
```

полный перевод массива валидации:

```
return array(
    ':field must contain only letters'                     => ':field должно содержать только буквы',
    ':field must contain only numbers, letters and dashes' => ':field должно содержать только буквы, цифры и подчеркивания',
    ':field must contain only letters and numbers'         => ':field должно содержать только буквы и цифры',
    ':field must be a color'                               => ':field должно быть кодом цвета',
    ':field must be a credit card number'                  => ':field должно быть номером кредитной карты',
    ':field must be a date'                                => ':field должно быть датой',
    ':field must be a decimal with :param2 places'         => ':field должно быть десятичным числом с :param2 количеством цифр',
    ':field must be a digit'                               => ':field должно быть целым числом',
    ':field must be a email address'                       => ':field должно быть адресом электронной почты',
    ':field must contain a valid email domain'             => ':field должно быть существующим адресом электронной почты',
    ':field must equal :param2'                            => ':field должно быть идентичным :param2',
    ':field must be exactly :param2 characters long'       => ':field должно быть длиной :param2 символов',
    ':field must be one of the available options'          => ':field должно быть одним из параметров',
    ':field must be an ip address'                         => ':field должно быть ip-адресом',
    ':field must be the same as :param2'                   => ':field должно равняться :param2',
    ':field must be at least :param2 characters long'      => ':field не должно быть короче :param2 символов',
    ':field must not exceed :param2 characters long'       => ':field не должно быть длиннее :param2 символов',
    ':field must not be empty'                             => ':field не должно быть пустым',
    ':field must be numeric'                               => ':field должно быть числом',
    ':field must be a phone number'                        => ':field должно быть номером телефона',
    ':field must be within the range of :param2 to :param3'=> ':field должно находиться между :param2 и :param3',
    ':field does not match the required format'            => ':field не соответствует требуемому формату',
    ':field must be a url'                                 => ':field должно быть URL-адресом',
);
```